# JSONparser reading first word in the sentence

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using GSON library to generate json object by taking inputs from variables and   json object also contains array, which is string type.

I tried the following:

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.StringReader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
    import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
    import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
    import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
    import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;


class Hello() {

public void process() {

    List<String> notifications = new ArrayList<String>();
            notifications.add("user got notification from web1");
            notifications.add("user got notification from web2");
            notifications.add("user got notification from web3");

            JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
            jsonObject.addProperty("type", "normal");
            jsonObject.addProperty("text", "hello world");


            JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
            for(String msg : notifications) {
                JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
                JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(msg));
                reader.setLenient(true);
                JsonElement element = jsonParser.parse(reader);
                array.add(element.getAsString());
            }

            jsonObject.add("notifications", array);

            String result = jsonObject.toString();
            System.out.println(result);

}

public static void main(String a[]) {

new Hello().process();
}
}
```

But when I execute this program, I am getting following output

```
{"type":"normal","text":"hello world","notifications":["user","user","user"]}
```

In the output, I can see that only first word being picked from the string array; how to get the full text;

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you **must** use JsonParser, but this seems to work

```
        for (String msg : notifications) {
//            JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
//            JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(msg));
//            reader.setLenient(true);
//            JsonElement element = jsonParser.parse(reader);
            JsonPrimitive prim = new JsonPrimitive(msg);
            array.add(prim);
        }
```

The output is:

{"type":"normal","text":"hello world","notifications":["user got notification from web1","user got notification from web2","user got notification from web3"]}